# Definition of interactive device

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, standards

According to the C++11 standard (§1.9.8):

> The input and output dynamics of interactive devices shall take place in such a fashion that prompting output is actually delivered before a program waits for input. What constitutes an interactive device is implementation-defined.

How does GCC, Clang and other compilers define "interactive device"?

Answer (score 1):

I guess that section was written with something like the CINT C++ interpreter in mind.

- http://root.cern.ch/drupal/content/cint

But I don't think the current status of CINT is very standard conformant.

Comment: I would like also to know why a "interactive-device" is not defined in the GCC Manual, since it is a "implementation-defined" concept (although it isn't an "implementation-defined behaviour").

Answer (score 0):

The answer is going to be as simple as a device running a program that requires both output to the user (for the user to understand or process) and input from the user (for the computer to process). It's something that will wait for user input at some point.